# How can I check if object is of custom type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I looked everywhere and couldn't find any way to check if a given object is of some custom type or not.
For example, I declare type Human as such:

`type A = { name: string; age: number; }`

Then I want to have a function that will receive an object and decided whether it's of type Human or not. Something like:

`isOfTypeHuman = (input) => typeof input === Human`

I have a feeling it's impossible, but I thought maybe I'm missing something.
Any ideas?

Comment: Human doesn't exist at runtime, are you talking about a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)?

Comment: You can use [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). Or since you've define a type for the object, then you can rely on TS since it will only allow objects that are assignable to `A` to be used as `A`. However, if you have an object of unknown shape, then you can only duck type it.

Comment: @VLAZ but how can I check that it doesn't have any unwanted properties (that aren't 'name' nor 'age' ?

Comment: Why would it matter? You can only access name and age through the Human interface anyway.

Comment: Check if there are any more keys? Although, in practice it rarely matters if there are more properties. If you get an object that also has an `employeeId` it doesn't mean it's *not* a human. Just a different type.

Comment: In my case it does matter... i'm basically looking for something like instanceof for types. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4):

Types do not exists at runtime. They are a only useful at compile-time, and stripped away afterwards.

You are required to check yourself:

```
// if it quacks like a duck..
isOfTypeHuman = (input) => input.name !== undefined && input.age !== undefined
```

You can additionally use user-defined type guard to make the rest of the code aware that that's a Human

```
isOfTypeHuman = (input: any): input is Human => input.name !== undefined && input.age !== undefined
```

Comment: but how can I check that it doesn't have any unwanted properties (that aren't 'name' nor 'age' ?

Comment: that's duck typing for you. you need to make those assertion yourself. `input instanceof ConcreteHumanClass` and the like. you actually need to parse input. you can get all the keys of the object with `Object.keys`, and check for a match with what you expect. Up to you to decide how strict you want to be. In most all the cases, that's unnecessary to do tho.